# C#: Remote database connection and network path not found issue

Tags: c#

i am in very difficult scenario. i have developed a windows application which fetch data from remote database and show those data. remote database is in shared hosting of orcsweb company.

when i am running the application from my IDE or exe in my pc it is working fine but when other people in same office run the exe from their pc then error coming like **network path not found**

the difference between my pc and other pc is that my pc has no antivirus installed and in other pc cloud based symantect  antivirus installed.

so i just guess antivirus is blocking remote database call ?

sample code which i use to connect remote db is here.

```
  private bool SaveData()
          {
              bool retvalue = false;
              int ret = 0;
              try
              {
                  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconn"].ConnectionString))
                  {
                      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_GSData", con))
                      {
                          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                          cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpDate.Value;
                          con.Open();
                          ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                          retvalue = true;
                      }
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  retvalue = false;
                  MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
              }
              return retvalue;
        }
```

### connection string in config file

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbconn" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

please tell me where is the mistake. how to unblock the remote db connection if antivirus is blocking. please guide me in details. thanks

Comment: Try to run ping to db server from other people computer. Check if you can reach database server.

Comment: yes they ping and they could access our remote db. i am in wired problem. not being able to understand how to sort it

Comment: It seems to be a firewall problem. Can you try to really connect to db from another computer (with sql server or another client)

Comment: Most probably they need to add a rule allowing data for sql server port. Default value is 1433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to one of the machines in question - if so, try turning off the anti-virus and firewall while you test what is happening, just to rule that scenario out.

More likely would be that the SQL Server instance is not configured for remote connections in which case you need to allow that before attempting to connect to it.

Comment: it started working when exe path with exe name has been added in AV exclusion list. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a possibility, try to turn off the antivirus at your colleague pc or ask you IT dept. to do this for you.

Do you use same network as your colleagues do?